# Passing function as named argument in flutter stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this fn which I want to pass to another Stateful widget -

```
class _AuthenticationControllerState extends State<AuthenticationController> {
  User user =
      User();
  int currentScreen = 1;

  switchScreenFn(int nextScreen) {
    setState(
      () {
        currentScreen = nextScreen;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Center(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              switch (currentScreen) {
                case 1:
                  return const ConversationsController(
                    switchScreenToAuthenticationScreenFn: switchScreenFn,
                  );
                default:
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text('Authentication!'),
                  );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how the Stateful widget is accepting the above mentioned function -

```
class ConversationsController extends StatefulWidget {
  const ConversationsController(
      {this.switchScreenToAuthenticationScreenFn, super.key});

  final Function? switchScreenToAuthenticationScreenFn;

  @override
  State<ConversationsController> createState() =>
      _ConversationsControllerState();
}
```

Why is that I am getting an error on this line on the first Stateful widget -

```
          return const ConversationsController(
            switchScreenToAuthenticationScreenFn: switchScreenFn,
          );
```

Here is the snip on what the IDE says-
[image]

Comment: just remove the const keyword !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a function that can't be `const` in this case. You can remove the `const`.

```dart
   return ConversationsController(
            switchScreenToAuthenticationScreenFn: switchScreenFn,
          );
```